# calling Medhod from a twig template and getting entityManager

Tags: symfony, entitymanager, sonata-admin

I wanna add a button in the sonata admin list grid depending if the object satisfies a condition or not.

I have a customize type template with this code :

```
{% if object.myMedhod == true %}

///if response is true add a button in sonata admin list grid

{% endif %}
```

my entity extends a model class where I have myMedhod()

my ModleClass:

```
namespace myprject/myBundle/Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class XModel
{

private entityManager;

public function __constuct(EntityManager $entityManager)
{
     $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

public function myMethod()
{
    $this->entityManager->getDoctrine()->getRepostiroy(xxx)->find(xxx)

}

}
```

my service:

```
services:
 my_service:
     class: myProject/myBundle/Model/XModel
     arguments: 
             - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```

I think all in my code is right but  I get a issue getting the entityManager... seems how if the construct method from the class is not called!!

the bug that throw symfony is :

Call to a member function getDoctrine() on a non-object

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Ok I have solved changing the approach!

in the twig template instead use the object  and call to a method in the a model class,

I call now the a method in the adminClass and I pass the object  so:

```
{% if admin.myMedhod(object) == true %}



{% endif %}
```

then in the service form the adminClass I added

calls:
            - [setSecurityContext, [@security.context]]
            - [setEntityManager , [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]]

in the admin Class :

```
public function setEntityManager($entityManager) {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
public function getEntityManager() {
    return $this->entityManager;
}

public function myMedhod($object){

    $condition=$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(xxx)->findOneBy(array("field"=>$object->getId()));


   if(empty($condition)){
   return true;
  }else{
   return false;
  }

}
```

thanks for your help everybody

Comment: why do you want to inject entity manager to an entity class ?

Comment: I don't want... I want to do it in a class which is extended by an Entity. To access from the template to his method and do a query to the db.

Comment: For what is responsible your model `myprject/myBundle/Model/XModel` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must create a twig extention whith a custon filter or custom function to make this. you don't need to call entity manager in your model.

See this page to understand how you can adapt your service to add a twig extension :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html